# How can I find the correct word order for Marshallese sentences?

Tags: resource-request, grammar, austronesian-languages

I am trying to make a set of cards (for the card game "Kloo") in the Marshallese language. It's basically color-coded for noun, verbs, etc... to be placed in a certain order. How do I discover the proper word-order in Marshallese? I am finding very few resources for this language.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the language (ML) used on [Marshall Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Islands), population 50K.

I am not sure why you are making such card game - do you know other ML speakers?

Trick is to find a speaker of a rare minor language like Marshallese.

I would try to look over online sites like couchsurfing or AirBnB for those islands, and contacted several locals.

Prepare good profile for yourself, with few photos, so your request is from someone relateable, not just anonymous faceless stranger.

Consider if you can provide some service in return - maybe if you can fix grammar mistakes in their descriptions, they might be more willing to help you in return. Even if, according to [Ben Franklin Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Franklin_effect) it might not be necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most comprehensive resource I could find on the language.

[http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/~rscook/pdf/PCMLT-JejeinM.pdf